# Why don't IDEs highlight string data type in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I am using Sublime Text 3 and Atom to code C and C++. But they don't highlight string data type as shown below.

[image]

This issue is frustrating me when I use Atom and Sublime. This doesn't happen in Visual Studio Code.

Are there any ways to fix this issue except using Visual Studio Code instead?

Comment: Because none of them is IDE. You may install c++ language server protocol plugin or something like that, but I'm not sure whether it will work or not.

Comment: Use a better plugin/color scheme?

Comment: I think Atom fixed this by something called as "Tree-sitter" parsers about two years ago. BTW, I seriously don't find any use of using more than one text-editor to write code!

Comment: Try installing : https://atom.io/packages/ide-cquery. You can define your own colors for semantics highlighting  in atom settings. For sublime-text define your own sublime-syntax file or download the same from numerous examples available online

Comment: Having tried installing IDE-CQuery, I've got this error `cquery language server for C++ unable to start`. Are there other ways to fix?

Comment: @LiuBei https://github.com/cquery-project/cquery/wiki

Comment: @brc-dd I have found Tree-sitter. This solved my problem. But how about Sublime Text 3? Are there any ways to fix?

Comment: `int`, `char`, and `double` are keywords, and `string` is not. I, for one, think this formatting makes sense.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But it should be highlighted as a classname. No comments if atom doesn't highlights them also!

Comment: @LiuBei Try installing the extensions mentioned in this article: https://www.freshtechtips.com/2015/03/sublime-text-c-cplusplus-add-ons-packages.html or try changing the syntax to https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/blob/master/C%2B%2B/C%2B%2B.sublime-syntax

Comment: @brc-dd Fixed!!! I've just installed C++ Starter Kit. The problems are all fixed!!! Thank you and please post your solution so that I can give you an upvote and make it an answer.

Comment: Side note: Don’t #include anything from bits/. Those are not official headers, but implementation details of GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Atom:

1. Press `Ctrl + ,(comma)` to open Settings.
2. Go to Settings > Core.
3. Check `Use Tree-sitter Parsers for supported languages.`

Additional Steps:

1. Install [Atom language support for C/C++ (Official)](https://atom.io/packages/language-c) or [C++14 language support (3rd Party)](https://atom.io/packages/language-cpp14).

For Sublime Text 3:

1. Install [C++ Starting Kit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2B%20Starting%20Kit) or [C Improved](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%20Improved) or [C++11](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2B11).

Note: The extensions/packages mentioned in this post are made by respective open source developers. I do not intend to promote a certain product.